# HSTS should be minimum 180 days, why?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, hsts

I did a test of my site at ssllabs.
I enabled HSTS for 90 days because I don't know how long I'll use SSL, and my current certificate ends in 89 days.

Now I got the warning:

> TOO SHORT (less than 180 days)  max-age=7776000

And that leaves me wondering, why the minimum of 180 days. Whats the reasoning behind a long HSTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longer the better, SSLLabs has decided that 180 days is their threshold for safe enough. If you're a smaller website, it is very possible that someone won't visit again with the 90 day window so they wouldn't be protected by HSTS. If you already have it at 90 days you kind of might as well set it to a year or more, since you can't just turn off TLS after that. Remember it isn't 90 days from when you enable HSTS, it's 90 days from the last visit from a given browser.

Comment: So they go for the slight suspicion someone might revisit your site at some arbitrary point in time? I enabled it to users in a session wouldnt use up redirect rules. Guess goals differ heh. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Two issues: First for a single session 90 days is overkill (unless your average session length is 90 days). Second, you still need to do the initial redirect on the first page load so it doesn't help there. HSTS exists to implement trust-on-first-use protections against MITM TLS stripping.

Comment: I realise that it doest help on first hit, but on secondary hits. The stripping I didnt know. I thought it was just a nifty trick to shift the redirect to https burden to the user.